# Do I need to fix this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

*She detested idiocy and praised intelligence. She was a trailblazer, the sheer force behind their success*.

I left out *and* from the second sentence because somehow the *comma* sounded more appropriate to my ears as I read the sentences to myself. Is this elision a solecism or could I drop *and* without eroding grammar?

Thank you

Comment: Do we say 'idiocy' or talk about 'idiots' in formal documents these days? I know that in many countries, including mine, pejorative language about mental handicap is considered disrespectful and unpleasant, and using these terms about the perceived poor performance of normally able people is especially deplored.

Comment: It's a matter of style.  If the style suits you, use it.

Comment: You could say that about _Mein Kampf_.

Comment: You sometimes see, often in obituaries, that someone 'did not suffer fools gladly', and this is frequently said with deliberate ambiguity, and can be interpreted to mean that the person was hateful towards people who did not agree with them, or who did not appear to have their self-assessed stellar grasp of some topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might sound stylistically better without an 'and', with 'the sheer force behind their success' in apposition to 'an original trailblazer'. However, in my opinion, there isn't the sense of explanation that this sort of apposition requires. The final noun/determiner phrase is a connected thought (hence fine used in the same sentence) but a separate thought. I'd have to include the 'and'.

Compare

- He is a scholar and a gentleman.

Contrast

- Los Angeles – a large city, a city of almost four million people – has had severe traffic problems in the past.

The 'and' is required where the two NPs are connected rather loosely ('but' would be required for a true contrast). A comma is used for an appositive that is a restatement, an expansion, an explanation or a closish synonym. Though in some cases even with some of these, 'and' may be chosen for emphasis.